# O que significa no PHP quando mysqli_num_rows retorna -1?

Tags: php, mysql

Em uma consulta ao MySQL o retorno do resultado traz o valor de -1, o que isto quer dizer? Sei que 0 é quando não traz nenhum resultado.

Comment: Edite a pergunta e poste o código para analisarmos. Não tem como sabermos o que causou sem saber o que você fez. Pode nem ser isso que esta retornando o -1, pode ser simplesmente confusão no uso do código.

Comment: Lembrando que mesmo fechada, a pergunta pode ser editada. Ao [edit] colocando o código você abre uma possibilidade de reabertura e melhor análise do problema real. Em resumo, até o momento o que dá pra concluir é o que já foi respondido abaixo: a consulta falhou, e precisa ver qual o erro retornado pelo mysqli_error e/ou mysqli_errno.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 3):

Tem certeza que recebeu isto nesta função? A [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) não indica que isto é possível, mas também não indica que não acontece. A documentação do PHP é muito ruim mesmo, por isso acho que pode haver uma falha aí.

É quase certo que indica um erro na chamada da função. Ou seja, não é que não tem linhas retornadas na consulta, a consulta falhou e nem 0 linhas ele gerou. Verifique se operações anteriores foram bem sucedidas.